# Printing paragraphs with newline characters

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, scanf

I have to write a C program where the output should be the same as the input but with all the vowels removed. Everything works except my program doesn't print out newline characters between sentences. I have to use printf and scanf.

Input:

```
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.
A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked.
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?

Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
How many pickled peppers that Peter Piper picked?
```

My program's output:

```
Ptr Ppr pckd  pck f pckld ppprs. pck f pckld ppprs Ptr Ppr pckd.f Ptr Ppr pckd  pck f pckld ppprs,Whr's th pck f pckld ppprs Ptr Ppr pckd?Whr's th pck f pckld ppprs Ptr Ppr pckd?Whr's th pck f pckld ppprs Ptr Ppr pckd?Whr's th pck f pckld ppprs Ptr Ppr pck ...
```

It doesn't seem to print out the `\n` after sentences.

This is my code:

```
void check_and_print_consonants(char string1[], char string2[]) {
     int vowel = 0;
     int str1_len = strlen(string1);
     int str2_len = 10;
     for (int i = 0; i < str1_len; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < str2_len; j++) {    
             if (string1[i] == string2[j]) {
                  vowel = 1;
             }
         }
         if(vowel == 0){
            printf( "%c", string1[i]);
         }
         else{
            vowel = 0;
         }
     }
}

int main(void) {
    //collect input in an array
   
    char input[128];
    char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    
    while (scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", input) != EOF){
        check_and_print_consonants(input, vowels);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You don't print the `\n`, so it's normal that there are no line endings in your output. Did you try to debug this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use library functions such as `memchr`, `strchr`, `strspn` and `strcspn`?

Comment: Well, maybe just print `\n` after `.`, `,` and `?` if it could solve a problem? :)

Comment: Use`fgets()`, not `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", input)` specifically ignores newline characters

```
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", input)
       ^^^^^^^^   . . . . . .  read everything but a newline character
               ^^^  . . . . .  ignore one character (the newline)
```

So you need to add a newline yourself at some place(s).

As suggested, I'd read the input character-by-character and print directly immediately afterwards expect in case of a vowel.

```
// loop {
//    get a char
//    if it is not a vowel print it (includes printing newlines)
// }
```

Comment: Detail: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", input)` reads nothing if the line is `"\n"`.  It also fails to read _everything but a newline character_ with a long line.

Answer (score 1):

Why to read the input line by line? you run the risk of making a mistake with the newline character!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch(c) {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            continue; /* ignore */
        }
        putchar(c); /* output */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do it like that :

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *input = "peter parker\npiper parker\neminem's rapper\n";
    char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i += 1) {
        for (int j = 0; vowels[j] != '\0'; j += 1) {
            if (input[i] == vowels[j]) {
                i += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

- the first for loop is here to navigate through your input ( Line 10 )
- the second for loop is here to compare every vowels with each char in your input array ( Line 11 )
- the if statement is to avoid printing the vowels which only bypasses vowels and not \n ( Line 12 )
- the break keyword is to stop the second for loop when you find a vowel ( Line ( Line 14 )

you can easily add scanf.

If you need help feel free to ask me :)